# Regex for finding attributes in BB code-like tags

Tags: regex

I need help with a regex to figure out if a BB-code like tag contains an attribute or not.

I have a [col] code which can have attributes as class and desktop. I want to ignore all those that have desktop attribute.

The one I came up with is:
`\[\bcol(?!\b.*desktop).*`

It works for test case 1 and 2 but fails for case 3 if they are on the same line. For test case 3, it should highlight the two columns without the desktop attribute.

Test Cases:

```
 1
 [col class="blue" desktop=8]
 [/col]
 [col]
 [/col]

 2
 [col class="green"]
 [/col]
 [col desktop=8]
 [/col]
 [col]
 [/col]

 3
 [col class="gray"] Some Column [/col][col desktop=8 class="blue"]Another column[/col][col class="gray"]Column 3[/col]
```

Comment: You may try [`\[col\b(?!(?:(?!\[col\b).)*?\bdesktop=).*?\[/col]`](https://regex101.com/r/xsvyv2/1) (with dotall modifier)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\[col\b(?!(?:(?!\[col\b).)*?\bdesktop=).*?\[/col]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsvyv2/1). The pattern requires a DOTALL modifier, or replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.

**Details**

- `\[col\b` - a whole "word" `[col`
- `(?!(?:(?!\[col\b).)*?\bdesktop=)`  - a negative lookahead failing the match if the pattern is matched immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `(?:(?!\[col\b).)*?` - any char not starting a whole word `[col` sequence, zero or more occurrences, as few as possible
  - `\bdesktop=` - a whole "word" `desktop=`
- `.*?`  - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\[/col]` - a `[/col]` substring (in some cases, `/` needs to be escaped).

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/5esnbe/1

`(?s)\[col(?![^\[]*desktop).*?\[/col\]`

Should match all except `desktop` cols. Let me know if this works, will explain the regex.